# Fields do not appear in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

The fields are not displaying in visualize section neither under Terms nor Significant Terms but are available in discover page. What should i change to make fields available in Visualize?

I have tried with keywords and text as type.

**Mapping:**

```
PUT /vcmts-new
{
  "mappings": {
    "build": {
      "properties": {
        "rel_ver": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "build_time": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "rel_status": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "rel_tags": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "job_num": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Document Example:**

```
POST /vcmts-new/build
{
  "rel_ver": "2.6.7.1-1-auto14",
  "build_time": "2018-05-21",
  "rel_status": "fail",
  "rel_tags": "PI09",
  "job_num": 22
}
```

**Discover page**
[image]

**Missing fields in Visualize page**

[image]

PS: The data is added manually, there is no logstash or other forwarders configured

Comment: Change the mapping from text to keyword since they are single terms or enable fielddata on the text fields. See here for details https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using keyword instead of text as the type helped make those fields as aggregatable. One also needs to either refresh the Index Patterns under Management or restart Kibana to reflect the changes. Simply refreshing the visualize tab wont help.